# Why I'm getting incorrect syntax near "Letter"?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqlclient

I'm trying to ADD new car details to the system. I want to add to the varchar values for the CarId. In the database type of the carId is varchar.

This is my code:

```
private void btnAddCar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
if (txtCarId.Text == "" || txtModel.Text == "" || txtColor.Text == "" || txtFuelType.Text == "" || txtPrice.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Missing Information");
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    Con.Open();
                    string query = "insert into CAR(CarID,Model,Color,FuelType,Available,Price) values(" + txtCarId.Text + ",'" + txtModel.Text + "','" + txtColor.Text + "','"+txtFuelType.Text + "','"+cmbBoxAvailable.SelectedItem.ToString()+"',"+txtPrice.Text+")";
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, Con);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    MessageBox.Show("Car Successfully Added");
                    Con.Close();
                    populate();
                }
                catch (Exception myEx)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(myEx.Message);
                }
            }
        }
```

But when I input values to the CarId textBox,
an exception occurs: "Invalid Column name" , Incorrect Syntax near"Letter"[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4uY1s.png)

Comment: SQL Injection alert. Don't concatenate parameters to a make a SQL query.

Comment: Have you looked at what actually ends up in `query`? If yes, and it doesn't answer your question, could you please share with us what is in that string?

Comment: cool, let's type `' or 1 = 1; delete table CAR --`  into your textbox and see what happens.

Comment: Presumably the combination of the individual parameters results in an invalid query, which is because you're using string concatenation to add your parameters.

Comment: Not only would parameters make the query safer, it's actually *easier* to construct a sound query containing them vs string concatenation.

Comment: It also looks like you have a SqlConnection object that you re-use. That's another bad pattern, SqlConnections are meant to be created and disposed of for each transaction.

Comment: apart from the already mentioned SQL-injection-vector: what is "letter"? I can't see it anywhwere.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0

Switch to use query parameters, do not make your life hard

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain I assume one of the parameters has something like `"the 'Letter' is 'A"` and it's messing up the query.

Comment: From JustinThns: *Please take a look at how you the + smybols in the SQL query. Execute this query without the variables first. Just try it with strings first and than add the variables in it. Execute it in SQL.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to make an attempt at fixing your code and hope it solves your issue or at least makes it clearer what is going wrong. Here is the new code:

```cs
private void btnAddCar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txtCarId.Text == "" || txtModel.Text == "" || txtColor.Text == "" || txtFuelType.Text == "" || txtPrice.Text == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Missing Information");
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            using (var con = new SqlConnection(<your connectionstring goes here>)
            {
                con.Open();
                string query = "INSERT INTO CAR(CarID,Model,Color,FuelType,Available,Price) VALUES(@CarID,@Model,@Color,@FuelType,@Available,@Price)";
                using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@CarID").Value = txtModel.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Model").Value = txtModel.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Color").Value = txtColor.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@FuelType").Value = txtFuelType.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Available").Value = cmbBoxAvailable.SelectedItem.ToString();
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Price").Value = txtPrice.Text;
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    MessageBox.Show("Car Successfully Added");
                }
                populate();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception myEx)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(myEx.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

So, the SqlConnection is now local and wrapped in a using pattern, so it will be closed and disposed automatically. The same goes for the SqlCommand.

The query is using parameters, so that Sql Injection is prevented and you don't have to think about the database types. That's not quite true, since I assume all database fields are strings, that's highly unlikely, but you haven't specified otherwise. The fields that are not strings, you will have to convert to the right type before setting the value of the parameter.

In real life you would put all the database stuff in a data layer and only deal with the user interface here, but I left that for yourself to sort out.

Also you shouldn't catch Exception, but the Exception subtypes that are likely to occur.

Comment: You didn't directly use AddWithValue here, but your code effectively does the same thing.  See [this blog post](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/) on why that should be avoided.

Comment: Well, lets be more specific here. The .add() should include the sqldbtype as the 2nd value and thus using .add() is still the better choice (if done correctly). So, .add() is the correct road to take - but "also" as you point out, the sqldbtype needs to be specified when doing so. What is depreciated is using add without .value and then the sqldbtype can be confused as a integer value. However, using .add() is preferred, but as you point out, the sqldbtype ALSO needs to be specifed here. And to be fair your link specific mentions this difference. So, .add() is good choice but with sqlldbType